# Where can I find documentation downloaded from Add/Remove software on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I have been playing around with the RPI4 and found that under Add/Remove software, that there is a section to download documentation. I installed a few of the packages that I thought would be interesting to read-up on, but I cannot find them anywhere on my pi. I looked online for solutions, but have not managed to find anything on this issue. I checked all of the files on my computer, and even when I run "whereis " it does not say where it is installed on the pi.

[image: RPI4 documentation downloads]

I did something like "whereis abs-guide-10-4" in the terminal with no success. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have not access to my device right now, but all the logs software related are in the /var/log/dpkg.log file. That includes every software added, removed and upgraded.

With the call like:

```
grep "install " /var/log/dpkg.log
```

You can obtain data with that action performed, changing install with upgrade or remove.

You can get further information and take a more theorical approach on the following [link](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/01/how-to-show-history-of-installed.html).

Have a noice day!